# Map the EF Object to the ViewModel Class without anonymous types

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

Is there a shorter version to map the EF from the linq or lambda expression to the View Model (*Movie* here is the ViewModel), knowing that the EF and the ViewModel have the same fields(Id, Director, Plot...) ?

```
public ActionResult MovieDetails(int ID) {


        using (MAKANI.Models.Entities db = new MAKANI.Models.Entities()) {


            var rMovie = (from m in db.Movies
                           where m.ID == ID
                           select new Movie {
                               Title = m.Title,
                               Director = m.Director,
                               Plot = m.Plot,
                               Link = m.Link,
                               Starring = m.Starring
                           }).Single();


            return View(rMovie);
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for a mapping framework - such as AutoMapper. http://automapper.org/

Comment: Not built in, while retaining proper separation between classes, no.